# How to design EVM machine in LabVIEW software

Tags: labview

I had an problem regarding design of EVM machine. 
Once the button is pressed a vote must be counted. So for that a counter is needed how to create that?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your project, I'd use a WHILE loop with an EVENT Structure. The Event Structure waits for a Value Change event on the button. On a change of a button, the corresponding value in the shift register is increased by 1 and displayed.

The snippet is missing the initialization of the indicators, since they are updated on the first click, only.

[image]